# How do I get the scroll view to occupy 100% of the screen height, even including the notch, is this possible?

Tags: react-native, scrollview

```
    import React from 'react';
import {View, Animated} from 'react-native';

const ProductLayout = props => {
  return (
    <Animated.ScrollView
      bounces={false}
      style={{
        backgroundColor: 'black',
      }}
      contentContainerStyle={{flexGrow: 1, flexShrink: 1, flexBasis: 1}}>
      <View
        style={{
          flex: 1,
          backgroundColor: 'green',
          width: '100%',
          height: 500,
          marginTop: 0,
        }}
      />
    </Animated.ScrollView>
  );
};

export default ProductLayout;
```

**strong text**
contentContainerStyle is taking a Safe Area, i need, all Area,  help!
How do I get the scroll view to occupy 100% of the screen height, even including the notch, is this possible?